# Is there a penalty for changing a generic function's argument based on `MyProtocol` to using the existential `any MyProtocol` or `some MyProtocol`?

Tags: swift, generics, existential-type

Normally in the discussion of things like `some`, they are referring to return types.  This question is specifically about using `any` or `some` in argument lists.

As an example, in the Swift documentation for `String`, you have this initializer...

```
init<T>(_ value: T, radix: Int = 10, uppercase: Bool = false)
where T : BinaryInteger
```

In Swift 5.6, they introduced the `any` keyword to let us work with existential types more easily.  With that change, I understand you theoretically can rewrite the above like so...

```
init(_ value: any BinaryInteger, radix: Int = 10, uppercase: Bool = false)
```

Of course there's also this version based on the `some` keyword, which also works...

```
init(_ value: some BinaryInteger, radix: Int = 10, uppercase: Bool = false)
```

My question is... which one makes the most sense? Is there a down-side to using the existential type over the generic like that? What about the `some` version? I was originally thinking yes, the generic version is best because the compiler can determine at compile time what's being passed to it, but then again, so does the existential `any` and even the `some` version as it won't compile if you don't pass it a `BinaryInteger` and I'm not quite sure how to write a test to check this out.

Comment: I found this recent article which claims they're expensive, apparently: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/existential-any/ : _"They’re more expensive than concrete types since they can store any value conforming to the protocol and since they can dynamically change. [...] existential types require dynamic memory. They also incur pointer indirection and dynamic method dispatch that cannot be optimized away. Without going into details about what this means, we can conclude that it’s better not to use `any` if you can."_

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110353 Here is a good talk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When passing a value of a protocol type `P` to a method in Swift, there are 4 possible spellings you can currently use:

1. `func f<T: P>(_ value: T)` ("generic")
2. `func f(_ value: some P)` ("opaque parameter")
3. `func f(_ value: P)` ("'bare' existential")
4. `func f(_ value: any P)` ("'explicit' existential")

Of these spellings, (1) and (2) are synonyms, and currently, (3) and (4) are synonyms. Between using (1) and (2), there is no difference, and between (3) and (4) there is currently* no difference; but between (1)/(2) and (3)/(4), there *is* a difference.

1. `f<T: P>(_: T)` is the traditional way of taking a parameter of a *concrete* type `T` which is guaranteed to conform to protocol `P`. This way of taking a parameter:

   - Gives you access to the concrete type `T` both at compile time and at runtime, so you can perform operations on `T` itself
   - Has no overhead, as the type `T` is known at compile time, and the compiler knows the size and layout of the value and can set up the stack/registers appropriately; it can pass whatever parameter was given to it directly to the method
   - Can only be called when the type of the argument is *statically* known (at compile time); but as such, can be called with protocol types with `Self`- or `associatedtype` requirements
2. Introduced in [SE-0341 (Opaque Parameter Declarations)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0341-opaque-parameters.md), the version of a method which takes `some Protocol` is *exactly* equivalent to the generic version spelled with angle brackets. I'll avoid repeating the content of the proposal, but the Introduction section spells out the desire for this syntax as a way to simplify the complexity of spelling generic parameters
3. `f(_: P)` is the traditional way of taking a parameter of an *existential* type which is guaranteed to conform to protocol `P`. This way of taking a parameter:

   - Does not give access to the concrete underlying type of the parameter at compile time; though this is accessible dynamically at runtime via `type(of:)`
   - Has runtime overhead both to pass an argument to the method, and when accessing the value inside of the method: because the type of the argument to the method might not be known statically (while the compiler still needs to know how to set up the stack and registers in order to call the method), the parameter must be boxed up in an "existential box", which has the interface of `P` and can dynamically pass methods along to the underlying concrete value. This both has a cost of allocating an additional "box" at runtime to hold the actual value inside of a consistently-sized and -laid-out container, as well as the cost of indirecting as method calls on the box must dynamically dispatch to the underlying type
   - Can be called whether or not the type of the argument is known statically; as such, *cannot* be called with protocol types with `Self`- or `associatedtype` requirements
4. Introduced in [SE-0335 (Existential Any)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0335-existential-any.md), the `any` keyword preceding a protocol type is a marker that helps indicate that the type is being used as an existential. It is *exactly* equivalent **right now** to using the bare name of the protocol (i.e. `any P == P`), but there has been some discussion about eventually using the bare name of the protocol to mean `some P` instead

So to address your specific example:

```swift
init(_ value: some BinaryInteger, radix: Int = 10, uppercase: Bool = false)
```

is exactly equivalent to the original

```swift
init<T>(_ value: T, radix: Int = 10, uppercase: Bool = false)
where T : BinaryInteger
```

while

```swift
init(_ value: any BinaryInteger, radix: Int = 10, uppercase: Bool = false)
```

is *not*. And, because `BinaryInteger` has `associatedtype` requirements, you also *cannot* use the `any` version as the existential type would not provide access to the underlying associated types. (If you try, you'll get the classic `error: protocol 'BinaryInteger' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`)

---

In *general*, generics are preferable to existential types when possible because of the lack of overhead and greater flexibility; but, they require knowing the static type of their parameter, which is not always possible.

Existentials are more accepting of input, but are significantly more limited in functionality and come at a cost.

Between preferring `<T: P>` and `some P`, or `P` and `any P` — the choice is currently subjective, but:

1. As part of SE-0335, it is currently planned that Swift 6 will *require* the use of the `any` keyword to denote existential protocol usage; the counterpart to using this is `some`, so if you want to start future-proofing your code and staying consistent, it might be a good idea to start migrating to `any` and `some`
2. Between opaque parameter syntax and generic syntax, the choice is up to you, but opaque parameters cannot currently cover all of the use cases that generics can, especially with more complicated constraints. Whether sticking with generics everywhere or preferring opaque parameters and using generics only when necessary is a code style choice that you'll need to make

Comment: There's also a discussion to be had about existentials vs. opaque types for variables and _storage_, as well as the new tools for "opening" existentials into their generic forms, but that might be a bit out of scope here; see [SE-0351 (Implicitly Opened Existentials)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0352-implicit-open-existentials.md) for more — it's a very powerful feature that helps bridge the gap between these types.

Comment: I certainly think that stylistically `any` should now be used rather than the bare protocol name, simply because it does a better job of saying what it means than the bare protocol name. The bare protocol name has misled and confused programmers all this time. It's good that `any` is going to be required.

Comment: Perfect answer, and very well thought-out/explained.  Thanks!  This is great to know. :)